# Using apt-get install in a live environment

Tags: apt, live-usb, live-environment

I would like to know where does data stores when I use apt-get install  in a live environment (2GB USB). Does this write data on the HDD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It writes it to the available RAM, thus when you restart your computer it will be gone... That is unless you are using a persistent USB Live Disc, Then it will put it on the flash drive, but at 2GB's you are going to fill it pretty quickly...

Comment: Thanks. That is everything I would like to know right now.

Comment: A 2 GB persistent area is usually quite sufficient for installing additional applications.

Comment: Yeah but you need 780(?)mbs for Ubuntu itself.... so there goes half your storage. I am not saying you can't install some apps, I am just saying your going to run out of room pretty quickly.